# How to change a html element that is later added using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem:

```
    <div class="container">
       <button id="buttonOne">ButtonOne</button>
       <button id="buttonTwo">ButtonTwo</button>
   </div>
   <p id="myParagraph">
     <br>
   </p>
```

And the following script :

```
<script>

var appendedInput = $('#buttonOne').one("click", function(event) {
  var myInput ="<input name=inputOne id="inputOneId"></input>;
  $('#myParagraph').append(myInput);
;})

</script>
```

**edited**

Ok. So I would like button two to perform just like button one, and either append a new element in the same paragraph, in the case scenario where button does not exist, or change #myInput with a button two generated input. I hope this is clearer now. Now I am even pondering why on earth would I want to do that ...
So my question is, how do I get my script to perform such a functionality?
If the yet unexisting element will exist, how do I change that element instead of adding a new element to the same paragraph. I am sorry it confuses people, I also find my issues very confusing, and this was a place to get answers.

***Later Edited Code***
With the help Of Jazz I am now trying you to mix .html with .append and get something seemingly going.

```
<script>
  var inputOne ="<input name='inputOne' id='inputOneId'></input>";
  var inputTwo ="<input name='inputTwo' id='inputTwoId'></input>";      

  var appendedInputOne = $('#buttonOne').one("click", function(event) {
      $('#myParagraph').append(inputOne);
;})

 var appendedInputTwo = $('#buttonTwo').one("click, function(event) {
     $('#myParagraph').append(inputTwo);
</script>
```

Now here is the following case scenario again. If button one is clicked, and then! button two is clicked, We have 2 input fields, and we are looking for just 1 input field in total. Button two should only append if there is no input field. I am right about to switch to php and solve this issue from php. But it's still a great Javascript problem lol

Comment: You have no button with id="button" in your code.

Comment: Yea. That's another bug :)

Comment: I am not sure how to ask this in a more specific way than I already am. In the case scenario where the user just simple clicks button one, and after clicks button two. How do I get to tag the content of the paragraph element ? Since we start with a not yet existing input field ?

Comment: What do want to change the existing input ? Can you add an example of the output you expect please ?

Comment: Your answer is in the post of @Shantanu. Use `.html()` function instead of `.append()` function.

Comment: I edited this JazZ. I hope now I am making more sense.

Comment: I am going to try and edit the code again. Maybe if the code is written better, I can make people understand. Sorry , Javascript is really not my strong point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this using plain Javascript, not jQuery, and changing some of the html. Here is what I was looking for..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "edited";
  }
  function mySecondFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<input></input>";
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>JavaScript in Head</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <button type="buttonOne" onclick="mySecondFunction()">Try Again</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it instead of appending it

with .html(value)

```
    <script>

    $("#buttonOne").on("click", function(event) {
          var myInput = "<input id='idInput' name='inputMe'></input>";
          $('#myParagraph').html(myInput);
     });

    $("#buttonTwo").on("click", function(event) {
          var myInput = "<input id='idInput' name='inputMe'></input>";
          $('#myParagraph').html(myInput);
     });

    </script>
```

Comment: Yes. That would make button two append a new input field. And what I am looking for is not to append a new input field, but to change, if existing , the current input. And if there is no existing input, only then, to append a new one to my paragraph ? Does this help ?

Comment: Your answer is closest to truth. I guess I will figure this one out by myself. Thank you so much for all the help. It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this [:button Selector](https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)

```
    <script>

var appendedInput = $(':button').on("click", function(event) {
  var myInput = "<input id='idInput' name='inputMe'></input>";
  $('#myParagraph').append(myInput);
;})

</script>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the OP's request correctly, this answer does not do what they're asking.

Comment: He want same functionality on click of both buttons.

Comment: His question is overall unclear, but he did clearly state he wants to **modify** the existing input with the click of buttonTwo.  Your answer just adds another input.

Comment: Yes . Its more of a "how can i change the yet unexisting input after it exists"

Comment: @AlexandraCeciliaMartinez Edit your question and clear out what you want!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you have 2 buttons and if the first one is clicked it should append a input field inside `<p id="myParagraph">`, that would be something like you already have:

```
$('#buttonOne').one("click", function(event) {
    var myInput = "<input id='idInput' name='inputMe'></input>";
    $('#myParagraph').append(myInput);
});
```

If the second button is clicked before the first one was clicked it should have the same functionality as the first click handler, so first of all refactor it into a function:

```
function appendInput() {
    var myInput = "<input id='idInput' name='inputMe'></input>";
    $('#myParagraph').append(myInput);
}

$('#buttonOne').one("click", function(event) {
    appendInput();
});
```

And now we add a new click handler for the second button, that checks if the input exists and handle the cases accordingly:

```
function appendInput() {
    var myInput = "<input id='idInput' name='inputMe'></input>";
    $('#myParagraph').append(myInput);
}

function changeInput() {
    var myInputValue = $('#idInput').val(); // get value of input field
    myInputValue = myInputValue + " <- changed"; // do your value changing here
    $('#idInput').val(myInputValue); // set value back to input field
}

$('#buttonOne').one("click", function(event) {
    if(!$('#idInput').length) { //this evaluates to false if the element exists
        appendInput();
    }
});


$('#buttonTwo').on("click", function(event) {
    if(!$('#idInput').length) { //this evaluates to false if the element exists
        appendInput();
    } else {
        changeInput();
    }
});
```

I hope that helps you, if not feel free to ask again or clarify your request.

```js
function appendInput() {
    var myInput = "<input id='idInput' name='inputMe'></input>";
    $('#myParagraph').append(myInput);
}

function changeInput() {
    var myInputValue = $('#idInput').val(); // get value of input field
    myInputValue = myInputValue + " <- changed"; // do your value changing here
    $('#idInput').val(myInputValue); // set value back to input field
}

$('#buttonOne').one("click", function(event) {
    if(!$('#idInput').length) { //this evaluates to false if the element exists
        appendInput();
    }
});


$('#buttonTwo').on("click", function(event) {
    if(!$('#idInput').length) { //this evaluates to false if the element exists
        appendInput();
    } else {
        changeInput();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
       <button id="buttonOne">ButtonOne</button>
       <button id="buttonTwo">ButtonTwo</button>
 </div>
 <p id="myParagraph">
     <br>
 </p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!